# If a US patent is published prior to 2001 do I use Kind Code "A" or "B1/B2"?

Tags: kindcode

If a US patent is published prior to 2001 do I use Kind Code "A" or "B1/B2" on my patent?

Answer (score 1):

No reason to even include the document type. If you do, use the designation that appears on the face of the document you are looking at.